# How Do I Change The Color on My Navigation Bar (CSS)

Tags: css, wordpress

This is driving me nuts. I have tried all of the suggestions in the other questions regarding this and it's just NOT working.

I need to change the background color my navigation bar. I don't want to change the CSS in the Editor section (Wordpress). I've been trying to get it done in the Edit CSS section.

```
#nav {
    position: relative;
    left: -90px;
}

nav > ul {margin: 40}
```

This is what I have so far (which has been working, it's centered the nav bar which I wanted, and put a margin between the header and nav bar). Is there anything I can add to this to change the color of the background (and then I'll need to change the color of the font, too..)

Answer (score 0):

Um, do you mean like this?

CSS:

```
#nav {
    position: relative;
    left: -90px;
    background-color: #7777777; /*Whatever color you want goes here, but in Hexadecimal form*/
}
```

And, for the font color(s):

```
#nav {
    position: relative;
    left: -90px;
    background-color: #7777777; /*Whatever color you want goes here, but in Hexadecimal form*/
    color: #1122cc; /*The color of your font also goes here, but in hexadecimal form*/
}
```

See these links for more reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_color.asp

COLORS:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colornames.asp

Answer (score 0):

For this HTML (I have duplicated each nav item to represent the "active" class added)

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="blue"><a href="#">Normal</a></li>
    <li class="green"><a href="#">Normal</a></li>
    <li class="red"><a href="#">Normal</a></li>
    <li class="blue active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
    <li class="green active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
    <li class="red active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I would use this CSS (note the CSS classes chained together, eg: .blue.active)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of changing the color. You can also use images or css to use gradients.

```
#nav {
    position: relative;
    left: -90px;
background-color: #336699; // change #000088 (blue) for the color your want
color: #FFFFFF; // change #FFFFFF (white) for the color you want.

}
```

You can use a [color picker](http://www.colorpicker.com/) to get the color you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're using the "class" selector instead of "id" in your HTML.

if it is class selector it should be:

```
.nav{
    background-color: #2d59a6  /*sample color*/
}
```

if it is id selector it should be:

```
#nav{
    background-color: #2d59a6 /*sample color*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
here's a example what I would do.

html:
<body>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>home</li>
        <li>about</li>
        <li>contact</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</body>`enter code here`
```

css:

```
nav{
/* this is without id else with # */
   
    background-color: black;
 /* you can choose any coler you want */

    color: #FFFFFF;
/*is to change yor font color*/

    text-align: center;
    /*    or you can use what you did  position: relative;left:-90px */
    font-family: fantasy;
/* with this you can choose any font that you want*/
}
body{
    background-color: #051D62;/* background color for the body   */

}
nav > ul{
    margin: 40px;

}
```